# How can I make the effect of moving an object in a very high speed?

Tags: animation

I've been planning to make an animation of moving a quad-copter and I was ready to model it and to animate it but I didn't know how do I animate the fans of the quad-copter so that it appears moving in a very high speed as in real life like this Photo :

[image]

In this image the fans are out of focus or something like that.
I want this also in my animation So how can I  make it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real life this effect you see on the image is done by the time a camera is opened to receive lights for a very small time (shutter speed). This time cannot be zero so it records a distorted image.

In blender when animating you don't have to do anything. Just tell your renderer to calculate the Motion Blur. For cycles you can find it in the property panel in the render tab.

[image]

For blender internal you need to enable the vector pass and use the Vector blur node in the compositor.